# Representing large pedigree chart as spreadsheet?

Tags: research-methods, pedigree

I'm working on a family history pedigree that is very wide with over 30 generations. I need to take **a lot of notes** about the various members and I need to see the pedigree in a semi-graphical manner while taking these notes and making comparisons.

An actual pedigree chart has become impossible to manage.  I got to thinking that perhaps a spreadsheet would be more efficient, but I've been hitting walls with whether to orient it vertically or horizontally since both have their advantages / disadvantages.

Has anyone had a familiar experience where a lot of information and research is going on simultaneously that needs to be captured with a somewhat visual representation of the relationships?

If so, what worked for you?

Are there better methods than a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

There are programs available of which I do not remember their names, that would some like what you would like but not quite. Naturally I don't remember the name, but there is a program you can enter as many generations as you like where blood relatives, adopted, illegitimate, relatives can be entered. It even allows you to not enter (skip) the relatives you do not know. It will print a descendants graph, I believe with and without the blood relatives. If your tree is tied to a single ancestor, I have no idea what it will do. It does not do a great job on ancestors except for blood relatives. Again, it will only graph sections of your tree at a time. The good part is the reference section where you can go directly to the relative if you know the name. And quickly if you know a close relatives name. I'm sorry I do not remember the name of the program. I do not use it because it is way to big for my research.